# Hide Formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, view, google-sheets-formula, formula, hide

do you know any solution on how to hide formula in google sheet from other users ?

Home > Data > Formula Bar

But it works for myself only

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve that in Google Sheets.

Although you can hide the formula bar from the UI, it indeed only applies to your user.

As a workaround, in order to hide/obfuscate a formula in a cell, you can create a spreadsheet reserved for those formulas, restrict/protect access of this spreadsheet to other users with access to the file and reference that cell (like `=MySheet!A1`) in the actual cell you’d like the result to be displayed.

Here is the [documentation page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656) for the protect/hide feature in Google Sheets.